# How do I select another input within the same div to change its background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically when a checkbox is checked, the accompanying text box background color needs to be green and red if unchecked.

```
<div class="col col-12">
    <input class="question" type="text" placeholder="Type question 1 here">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a1">
    <label for="a1"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="A">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a2">
    <label for="a2"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="B">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a3">
    <label for="a3"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="C">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a4">
    <label for="a4"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="D">
</div>
```

Comment: Would this work? `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .answer { background-color: green }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change',function(){
   var answer = $(this).closest('div').find('input.answer');
   // change BG
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look attached snippet.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
              $(this).next().next(".answer").css('background-color','green');
              
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                $(this).next().next(".answer").css('background-color','red');
              
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col col-12">
    <input class="question" type="text" placeholder="Type question 1 here">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a1">
    <label for="a1"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="A">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a2">
    <label for="a2"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="B">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a3">
    <label for="a3"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="C">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a4">
    <label for="a4"></label>
    <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="D">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in a script block after the answers section, or to run on document load:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  var color = $(this).is(':checked') ? 'green' : 'red';
  var css = {};
  css['background'] = color;
  var input = $(this).siblings('input.answer');
  input.css(css);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery.nextAll()`

Also not that you might want to `trigger` change handler initially

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('input.answer').removeClass('red green').addClass(this.checked ? 'green' : 'red');
}).change();
```

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col col-12">
  <input class="question" type="text" placeholder="Type question 1 here">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a1">
  <label for="a1"></label>
  <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="A">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a2">
  <label for="a2"></label>
  <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="B">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a3">
  <label for="a3"></label>
  <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="C">
</div>
<div class="col col-6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answer_group[1][]" id="a4">
  <label for="a4"></label>
  <input class="answer" type="text" placeholder="D">
</div>
```